# Less than 12 columns in a freshly installed Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I simplified the code to the maximum to make it readable. I changed nothing to the bootstrap folder. So here is the "simplified" HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-sm-3">3
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And what is displayed on my web browser(s) :

```
3
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
1 2 3
```

With a framing CSS script, I could manage to see that the "cut" happens approximatively at the middle of the ninth columns (instead of the end of the 12th).

Any idea ?

Comment: What happens when you remove `<div class="col-sm-3">` and it's respective closing tag and just have the `<div class="row">...</div>`?

Comment: It is not causing any problem. But it is not what I was looking for...

Add 1 :
Oh, and when a replace the 12 "1" col by 6 "2" col, I have no problem. It only occurs when I have at least 1 "1" col involved.

Comment: As Harsh said below, chances are col-sm-3 can't be divided into 12 columns.

Comment: That would be correct, the text is too wide for the width in this situation. There's also a number three just inside the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case u want to do so remove padding

```
.col-sm-1{
        padding:0 !important;
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with col-sm-3 ? What if i need it to be 3 ?

Comment: Let us consider a 500px width screen.You create 4 columns using col-sm-3 n then for each 12 columns ie 48 columns in total . Now for each div u only have 10 pixel n bootstrap requires a min of 30px

Comment: Ah ok I forgot this 30px thing, even if my screen displays much more than 500px, it should be this.

Comment: no that is just when u want much smaller add col-md-1 n others they ll have default padding

Comment: Ok, and do you have an idea why, in that "3" column, if i want to display an image.png I cannot control its size by the column ? Either I put it on a "1" column or a "12" one, it keeps the same size (yes, I am beginning with Bootstrap...)

Comment: <nav class="col-sm-3">  
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-sm-12"><img src="../images/logo.png"></div>  
          </div>  
</nav>

Comment: do u have jsfiddle link